# Crystal Report - Check the check box when the value of split array is the same with the given string value

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports-2008

I'm doing a multi-select on the crystal report. In the database, the value of the selected checkbox is separated with a comma like this (Blanking / Piercing, Bending, Dowelling). Now, I'm trying to display this on the crystal report with Font(Wingdings). Here's the code in Formula Fields on crystal report:

```
Stringvar array splitArr:= split({Press.Process}, ","); //Press.Process value are (Blanking / Piercing, Bending, Dowelling)
Numbervar i;

For i:=1 to UBound(splitArr) Step 1 do( 

if Trim(splitArr[i]) = "Blanking / Piercing" then
   Chr(254) //Display checkbox w/ check
else
   Chr(111) //Display checkbox w/ uncheck
);
```

But this code always gives me like this on crystal report preview:

[Checkbox List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wnP2.png)

It shows the snow flakes character not the checkbox. Please help me to this fix problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the second argument in the Split function, so you ended up splitting on space.
Change the code to something like:

```
local stringvar InputString := "Blanking / Piercing, Bending, Dowelling";
Stringvar array splitArr := split(InputString, ",");
Stringvar result := Chr(111);
Numbervar i;

For i:=1 to UBound(splitArr)  Step 1 do
( 
  if Trim(splitArr[i]) = "Blanking / Piercing" then 
  (
    result := Chr(254); //Display checkbox w/ check
    exit for
  );
);

result;
```